# Does ormlite support batch create and update, delete

Tags: android, orm, ormlite

Does ormlite  support batch operations(create and update, delete) on android?

I want to insert a lot of data in tables with one transaction.

for example: insert users, products.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.  Voter should have at least left a comment.

Answer (score 4):

```
getHelper().getDao().callBatchTasks(new Callable<Void>(){
            @Override
            public Void call() throws Exception {}}) ;
```

in call method, can insert multi object in it, and the speed is more faster than execute out of the method.